# use directive Drag and drop in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop

I join into my project directive drag and drop with :

https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists

I did it:

```
 <div ng-repeat="list in lists">
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;">
      <div id="tasks">
        <h3>{{ list.name }} {{$index}}</h3>

        <ul 
              dnd-list="list.cards"  
              dnd-drop="drop($parent.$index, $index, list._id)" 
         >
          <li 
                ng-repeat="card in list.cards" 
                dnd-draggable="card"  
                dnd-dragstart="logEvent($parent.$index, $index, list._id)"
          >
            {{card.name}} 
          </li>
        </ul>
```

And the problem is that when i set

```
 dnd-drop="drop($parent.$index, $index, list._id)"
```

in tag of li, this dnd-drop feature stops working.
If she is in tag ul and i set there ng-repeat is work i have $parent.$index and $index card but later I can't move for example first card to last card, because it always sets the penultimate. I tried to use other features but poorly with me with english and found nothing.

if left as it is at the beginning I have  thanks feature

```
dnd-dragstart="logEvent($parent.$index, $index, list._id)"
```

$index List and $index card which I raise it

and thanks

```
dnd-drop="drop($parent.$index, $index, list._id)"
```

$index list to which I transfer the card and still is problem, because I don't know how to make to have $indexCard...

Please help me someone to fix that by find the right feature, or idea how to transfer $index child to dnd-drop function.

EDIT:

https://jsfiddle.net/qz19qw8t/

$scope.lists =  Array [ Object, Object ]

$scope.lists[0] = Object { _id: "59c277ee0c002422e43ea49b", name: "1", __v: 0, cards: Array[5], created: "2017-09-20T14:15:10.278Z", updated: "2017-09-20T14:15:10.278Z" }

$scope.lists[0].cards[0] = Object { name: "1", position: 0 }

Comment: Can you provide fiddle or plunker please?

Comment: can u give me hosting where i can upload whole my project?? I am very concerned about solving this problem

Comment: No, but maybe you can try to use https://plnkr.co/ to create minimal angularjs app with  that directive and show the problem in action. Btw what is a $parent.index? Can you post more code (js, html) and the lists array?

Comment: i make edit, $parent.index i left because when i i gave up ng-repaet to ul tag its work but i cant do that. :/

Comment: Unfortunately that fiddle is not working at all, can you at least post example of lists aray (do console.log(JSON.sringify($scope.lists)) and copy here output from the console) and write what kind of drag and drop you whant to achieve (simple, nested, advanced...)

Comment: I dont use any demo with that but i use only feature its look like simple, without json and feature $watch and with jsfiddle i dont know how to make to work eh:/

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** I made new [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SgNJeLpFuUIvdqnJ4bjJ?p=preview)
I used just dropCallback function to retrive information about dropped items and where they were dropped.

```
 dnd-drop="dropCallback($index, item, lists)"
```

$index is index of lists array where card is dropped, item is card object, external is $scope.lists
I left comments in code and made list preview (list result).

```
<ul >
    <li ng-repeat="item in lists">
       {{item.name}} 
       <ul style="min-height: 30px" dnd-list="item.cards" 
        dnd-drop="dropCallback($index, item, lists)"
        >
         <li ng-repeat ="card in item.cards"
            dnd-draggable="card"
            dnd-moved="item.cards.splice($index, 1)"
            dnd-selected="models.selected = item"
            ng-class="{'selected': models.selected === item}"
             dnd-effect-allowed="move">
          {{card.name}}</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For moving list items you need to specify data-type which is execepted for drop (drop-type) and dnd-allowed-types. See the plunker for the rest.

Comment: Yes, nice, but how to save that after move to database, I need now after drop know on which position card and which list i drop item, Because thanks this knowledge I can make modifications on arrays. I use for that dragstart, and drop but I cant get $index card where i drop item because dnd-drop work only on ul and i have ng-repeat inside li

Comment: Ok understand, let me try to fix that.

Comment: This is my problem from 3 days, If u will help me, I will start walk to church :D

Comment: Also please add min height css property to inner list: <ul style="min-height: 30px;" dnd-list="item.cards" .. so you can drop items to the empty list.

Comment: Hey Can I contact you with any chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154993/discussion-between-bartlomiej-flis-and-lingthe).

Comment: Hey, lingthe can u look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380199/drag-and-drop-inoperative-function